# lstlisting in two column article

Tags: listings

I need to write an article in two columns, but I would like to span an lstlisting over both text colums. With figures and tables I use `\begin{figure*}`. But this does not work with `\begin{lstlisting*}`.

How can I span the listing over both columns in `twocolum` article format?